# Ho-Lee model - A and B derivation for $P(t,T)=e^{-A(t,T)-B(t,T)r_t}$

Tags: interest-rates, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-volatility

I am analyzing the transition of the bond prices in the affine models in the form of $P(t,T)=e^{-A(t,T)-B(t,T)r_t}$

using the property that the diffusion and the drift of an affine model can be presented as
$$b(t,r)=b(t)+\beta(t)r_t \quad \quad (1) $$ 
$$\sigma^2(t,r)=a(t)+\alpha(t)r_t \quad \quad (2) $$

where the A and B satisfy the system of the below ordinary differential equations
$$\partial_t A(t,T) = \frac{1}{2} \ a(t) \ B^2(t,T) - b(t) \ B(t,T), \quad A(T,T)=0 \quad \quad (3)$$
$$\partial_t B(t,T) = \frac{1}{2} \ \alpha(t) \ B^2(t,T) - \beta(t) \ B(t,T) -1 , \quad B(T,T)=0 \quad \quad (4)$$

I am trying to derive bond price P(t,T) for the **Ho-Lee model. $dr_t=\mu t dt + \sigma dW_t^*$** 
My understanding is that $b=\mu t, \ \beta=0, \ a=\sigma^2, \alpha=0$ will be the parameters for the eq (3) and (4), which gives

$$\partial A(t,T) = \frac{\sigma^2}{2} B^2(t,T) - \mu t \ B(t,T) \quad \quad (5)$$
$$\partial B(t,T) = -1 \quad \quad (6)$$
and further it should yield 
$$B(t,T)=T-t \quad \quad (7)$$

The last step is unclear to me. 
**My questions 

1) why T-t is is substituted for, not t or T 

2) why the integration $\partial B=-1$ results in (T-t)  and not -(T-t)? integrating a function f'(x)=-1 should give f(x)=-x, shouldn't it?**

$$A(t,T)=\frac{-\sigma^2}{6}(T-t)^3 + \int_t^T b(s)(T-s)ds \quad \quad (8)$$
giving the final equation $$P(t,T)=exp \ \big{(}\frac{-\sigma}{6}(T-t)^3  -\frac{\mu}{6} T^3 + \frac{1}{2} \mu T t^2 -\frac{1}{3} \mu t^3 - (T-t)r_t \big{)} \quad \quad (9)$$

**Question 3) 

How the integral $\int_t^T b(s)(T-s)ds$ gives $\frac{\mu}{6} T^3 - \frac{1}{2} \mu T t^2 + \frac{1}{3} \mu t^3$. I can't get the algebra here. Is this an ordinary integral?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Equation (6), $B(t,T)=-t+c(T)$ for some function $c(T)$. $1=P(t,t)=e^{-A(t,t)-(c(t)-t)r_t}$ or $A(t,t)+(c(t)-t)r_t=0,\,\forall (r_t,t)$. So $c(t)=t, A(t,t)=0,\forall t$.

For Equation (8) you have missed the square on $\sigma$ and a factor of $\frac13$. Then you just need to substitute in the function for $b(s)$ and integrate the following to get the correct result.
$$A(t,T) = -\frac{\sigma^2}{2}\int_t^T(T-s)^2ds +\mu\int_t^T s(T-s)ds.$$

Comment: did you mean P(T,T), A(T,T)?  and than c(T)=T ?  the notation is confusing

Comment: @Michal: Does it make any difference? The variables are place holders. You may as well write $P(x,x)$ and $c(x)=x$ or use any other symbols, Latin, Greek, Chinese, Arabic or Hobbitian.

Comment: ok, understood. One more question to that. Is the integral in the (8) an ordinary one. I can't get the right form of the P(t,T). Could you clarify that part please?

Comment: See the addition to my answer. Also do you not like my edit to your question? If you are keen to the clarity of notation, indicating which variable you are partial differentiating such as in Equations (5) and (6) is essential.

Comment: Are you able to integrate the integral in my answer?

Comment: yes, I am able to go through the algebra now, but I have some problem with signs in the equation for A. That's what I am getting $$A(t,T)=\frac{-\sigma}{6}(T-t)^3  -\frac{\mu}{6} T^3 + \frac{1}{2} \mu T t^2 -\frac{1}{3} \mu t^3$$

but the solution manual suggests
$$A(t,T)=\frac{-\sigma}{6}(T-t)^3  +\frac{\mu}{6} T^3 - \frac{1}{2} \mu T t^2 +\frac{1}{3} \mu t^3 \quad$$ cannot find any mistake, maybe there is a typo in the solutions, would you be able to tell which answer is correct?

Comment: The solution manual solution is correct. Do the second integral in my answer.

Comment: $$\int_t^T s(T-s)ds = \int_t^T (sT-s^2)ds= \quad  [\frac{1}{2}s^2T-\frac{1}{3}s^3]_t^T \quad =\frac{1}{2} T^3 -\frac{1}{3} T^3 -\frac{1}{2} t T^2+\frac{1}{3} t^3= \quad  \frac{1}{6} T^3 - \frac{1}{2}  T t^2 +\frac{1}{3}  t^3$$

Comment: which is then multiplied by $-\mu$. I see the issue. the minus comes from the eq.(3) and (5), but you have a plus in your answer and there is a plus in the eq(8) coming from the solution. why there is a plus?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39309/discussion-between-hans-and-michal).